# Как задать глобальные настройки виджета Yii2?

Tags: yii2, виджет

Есть к примеру такой повторяющийся код.

```
<?php

echo $form->field($model, 'requirements_ru')->widget(
    CKEditor::class,
    [
        'editorOptions' => [
            'preset' => 'standart',
            'inline' => false,
        ],
    ]
);

?>

<?php

echo $form->field($model, 'requirements_en')->widget(
    CKEditor::class,
    [
        'editorOptions' => [
            'preset' => 'standart',
            'inline' => false,
        ],
    ]
);

?>


<?php

echo $form->field($model, 'conditions_ru')->widget(
    CKEditor::class,
    [
        'editorOptions' => [
            'preset' => 'standart',
            'inline' => false,
        ],
    ]
);

?>

<?php

echo $form->field($model, 'conditions_en')->widget(
    CKEditor::class,
    [
        'editorOptions' => [
            'preset' => 'standart',
            'inline' => false,
        ],
    ]
);

?>
```

Как глобально указать настройки по умолчанию для определенного типа виджета, для ВСЕГО проекта?
Что бы не писать каждый раз.

```
[
    'editorOptions' => [
        'preset' => 'standart',
        'inline' => false,
    ],
]
```

Попытался переопределить настройки через внедрение зависимостей, таким кодом в начале кода формы, но не помогло.

```
Yii::$container->set('mihaildev\ckeditor\CKEditor', [
    'editorOptions' => [
        'preset' => 'basic',
        'inline' => false,
        'height' => 600
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Переопределите виджет, по умолчанию у себя поставьте настройки и пользуйтесь своим

Comment: @СергейМишин Можно дополнить ссылочкой для одаренных редким даром экстрагуглонемоты?

Comment: Ссылочкой на что? Как переопределять виджеты? Как обычные классы, через `extends`.  У вас же есть папка с виджетами своими например? Там Создаёте свой, только `extends CKEditor` и там прописываете настройки и, возможно, переопределяете метод `run {parent::run; }` (в этом не уверен) и дальше используете `app\widgets\MyCustomCKEditor`

Comment: @СергейМишин боюсь это не кошерное решение...

Comment: Что значит не кошерный, простите? По своему опыту и по опыту проекта, в котором сейчас участвую, могу сказать, что способ с переопределением - отличный вариант. Мы в проекте все виджеты переопределяем и используем уже свои, потому что вероятность того, что их придётся под себя перепиливать - 95%. Да и кто знает, что в голову автору стукнет и он там поменяет. Банально у виджета `Modal` различаются свойства для бустрапа 3 и 4. И вам очень повезёт, если у вас только затронутся свойства виджета, а не, например, ещё его шаблон. Но дело ваше, конечно же

Comment: @СергейМишин как правило там где я знаю как сделать по простому, но не знаю как сделать кошерно, я задаю вопрос с четкой формулировкой... Прочтите заголовок вопроса... Там нет ни слова про создание новых виджетов/переопределение/наделения магическим преводсходством и т.д., там конкретный вопрос, с конкретной формулировкой!

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос таким кошерным способом.
Идем в `\backend\config\bootstrap.php` если например как у меня, надо переопределить поведение виджета для бека.
Прописываем такой код.

```
Yii::$container->set('mihaildev\ckeditor\CKEditor', [
    'editorOptions' => [
        'preset' => 'basic',
        'inline' => false,
        'height' => 200
    ],
]);
```

Данный код, через глобальное внедрение зависимостей, установит для всех классов виджета типа `mihaildev\ckeditor\CKEditor` настройки указанные в параметрах метода `set`.

Comment: Это один из самых не кошерных вариантов. Потому что в таком случае контейнер будет наполняться этим классом всегда, даже, если он не нужен на странице. Сергей Мишин отличный вариант предложил.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = [
    'container' => [
        'definitions' => [
            'mihaildev\ckeditor\CKEditor' => [
                'editorOptions' => [
                    'preset' => 'basic',
                    'inline' => false,
                    'height' => 200
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ]
];
```

[Подробней](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/concept-configurations.md#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-)